# GWT code splitting synchronous request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, gwt

I´m using code splitting in GWT to reduce the size of the initial JavaScript.
While my application initializes, I want to prefetch the other (bigger) part of my code as explained in the docs (www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html).

```
private void doSth(final boolean prefetch) {
    GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Log.error("Loading the code failed!");
        }

        public void onSuccess() {
            if(prefetch)
                return; //do nothing. just a prefetch
            //here is the loaded code
        }
    });
}
```

But I cannot recognize a performance improvement. As I analyzed the browser logs, I recognized, that the request for loading the JavaScript is not marked as XHR. Does GWT load the code of a split point synchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance improvement is in the initial downloaded code, assuming nothing else references that code. If anything else does the work of `//here is the loaded code`, then there will be either very little or no code to break out into a separately downloaded JS file.

This feature can be disabled in several ways, including by using dev mode or setting a compiler flag to skip this process. In this case, yes, the split point runs synchronously, since it makes no sense to wait. Additionally, after the file has been loaded once, it does not need to be loaded the next time the code is invoked within the same page load.

If your server is set to cache correctly, then after the first visit the savings is even smaller since there is no download to do - you only save the time taken to parse that code into the browser's JS VM.

But beyond that, we're going to need more information.

---

Here's a quick demo showing how the split point can be written with a little more meat to it, and letting you use your browser to notice how the split point code was brought in separately.

```
public class SampleEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Label label = new Label("Hello, World!");
    label.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {
          public void onFailure(Throwable var1) {/*ignore*/}
          public void onSuccess() {
            Window.alert("Clicked, and loaded in split point!");
          }
        });
      }
    });
    RootPanel.get().add(label);
  }
}
```

Code and sample:
https://viola.colinalworth.com/proj/755e224e7f48a047703d44eb6903d926/project/client/SampleEntryPoint.java

Standalone sample:
https://viola.colinalworth.com:444/compiled/755e224e7f48a047703d44eb6903f76c/

When you load this page, the `nocache` file loads, as does the initial download (as seen through Chrome's inspector's Network tab):
[image: initial download after page load]

Then, when you click the Label widget, the onClick fires which triggers the runAsync and downloads the extra split point (plus the "leftover" fragment):
[image: additional downloads after split point]

After those two new entries have been added to your Network tab, you see the alert message appear. Subsequent clicks do not result in this slight delay, nor do they force this extra JS to download again.

Also note that these are not loaded as AJAX/XHR calls, but as a script tag to be added to the page. Clicking on the details in the Initiator column (not pictured) leads to this (formatted for readability):

```
function fb(a) {
    var b, c, d;
    d = (bb(), window);
    b = d.document;
    c = b.createElement('script');
    (!!a.a || a.b) && cb(c, a.a, a.b);
    eb(c, a.c);
    (b.head || b.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).appendChild(c);
    return c
}
```

Getting through the obfuscated code, we see that a `<script>` tag is created, and appended to the `<head>` of the page.

---

Digging in deeper, we can find that the `AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadingStrategy` interface describes how to go get this fragment, and that `com/google/gwt/core/AsyncFragmentLoader.gwt.xml` wires this by default to `XhrLoadingStrategy`. However, both the `xs` and `xsiframe` linkers change this, to `CrossSiteLoadingStrategy` and `ScriptTagLoadingStrategy` respectively. And as of recent versions of GWT (you didn't specify, so I'm assuming you are using a recent version), the `xsiframe` linker is the default. From Core.gwt.xml:

```
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
```

We can customize this by switching to the old linker, or just replacing the strategy. Note that switching the an XHR strategy will prevent cross-domain loading from working correctly (such as SuperDevMode), so be careful with this.

Much as `AsyncFragmentLoader.gwt.xml` wired the interface to `XhrLoadingStrategy`, and `CrossSiteIframeLinker.gwt.xml` changed it to `ScriptTagLoadingStrategy`, we can change it back. We create a rule that replaces `LoadingStrategy` with `XhrLoadingStrategy`, and list it after our GWT inherits statements in our .gwt.xml file:

```
<replace-with class="com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.XhrLoadingStrategy">
    <when-type-is class="com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.AsyncFragmentLoader.LoadingStrategy" />
</replace-with>
```

This is what the old default used to rely on as part of the `std` linker (`com.google.gwt.core.linker.IFrameLinker`), though this is no longer encouraged and may be removed in a later release.

Comment: Thank you for that great anwer. Exactly what i need. Is it possible to define the XhrLoadingStrategy (and overwrite the default settings) in the gwt.xml?

Comment: Yes, I'll clarify in the answer, but why are you hoping to use an XHR? That is going to break cross-domain loading (unless the server hosting the split point supports CORS), which will prevent SDM from working as expected.

Comment: The code of the application is huge. The code of the split point is 2MB! To improve the startup performance, I want to load the code of the split point asynchronously, while the client requests some other parameters from the server.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are telling/asking me. Split points (when they are enabled) are always async. If you have caching enabled on your server however, they will never load a second time (unless the app is changed/recompiled).

Comment: It´s hard to explain. It´s a very special case. But you already helped me a lot. thanks